# Snapcraft doesn't produce any snaps after cleaning the part

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, snapcraft

If I build my snap like this:

`$ snapcraft clean --use-lxd && snapcraft --use-lxd` it builds the snap for me.

However, this takes a lot of time as it every time downloads and installs huge amount of VM packages and I want to build only my app part `gnu-heimer`:

`$ snapcraft clean gnu-heimer --use-lxd && snapcraft --use-lxd`

This **seems** to work fine:

```
Priming gnu-heimer 
Snapping 'heimer' |                                                                                                                                                                 
Snapped 'heimer_1.18.0_amd64.snap'
```

But...no files produced:

```
$ ls *.snap                                            
ls: cannot access '*.snap': No such file or directory
```

What is going on?

My `snapcraft.yaml` is here if interested: https://github.com/juzzlin/Heimer/blob/master/snapcraft.yaml

**EDIT**: This could have something to do with the fact that I'm running this as "jenkins" instead of my regular user account, but I don't understand what and why.